# Why FormatException when decode JSON from string value (i.e. only [A-Z][a-z] characters?

Tags: json, dart, decode

Below the simple example

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() { 
  final numJson = '1';
  encode(numJson);
  decode(numJson);
  
  final strJson = 'a';
  encode(strJson);
  decode(strJson);  
}

void encode(value) {
  try {
    final enc = json.encode(value);
    print('enc = $enc');
  } on Exception catch(e) {
    print(e.toString());
  }
}

void decode(value) {
  try {
    final dec = json.decode(value);
    print('dec = $dec');
  } on Exception catch(e) {
    print(e.toString());
  }
}
```

This is the output:

```
enc = "1"
dec = 1
enc = "a"
FormatException: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

Why dart could not decode JSON ecoded `String` as `String`? Don't you think it is a bug?

Comment: You are *not* decoding a JSON encoded string. The `strJson` value is a string containing the letter `a`.
If you `json.encode` that string value, you get the JSON source `"a"`, which is the encoding of a string literal.
You then `json.decode` the string containing `a`, *not* the `"a"` JSON source, and the string `a` is not valid JSON.

Comment: `final strJson = 'a';` -- the value of `strJson` is not JSON. It is just the `a` letter. The string containing the letter `a` encoded as JSON looks like this: `"a"`. Do not attempt to build JSON manually. Always use `json.encode()` for this purpose.

Comment: @Irn the problem was I expected that Dart knows that if I decode `String` `'a'` it will fix the value to `'"a"'` somehow in `json.decode`.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your code is incorrect.
The following code is correct, but it is also meaningless, just like your code.

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  final numJson = '1';
  encode(numJson);
  decode(numJson);

  final strJson = '"a"';
  encode(strJson);
  decode(strJson);
}

void encode(value) {
  try {
    final enc = json.encode(value);
    print('enc = $enc');
  } on Exception catch (e) {
    print(e.toString());
  }
}

void decode(String value) {
  try {
    final dec = json.decode(value);
    print('dec = $dec');
  } on Exception catch (e) {
    print(e.toString());
  }
}
```

Output:

```
enc = "1"
dec = 1
enc = "\"a\""
dec = a
```

P.S.
I can't even imagine how you thought of writing such an algorithm.
Because it doesn't make any sense.

This algorithm is useless because it doesn't convert the results from one to the other.
**Below is a code that does not have this drawback and actually calculates at least something.**

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:test/test.dart';

void main() {
  _test('1', 1);
  _test('"a"', 'a');
  _test('{"a":1}', {'a': 1});
  _test('[1,"a"]', [1, 'a']);
}

dynamic decode(String value) {
  try {
    final dec = json.decode(value);
    //print('dec = $dec');
    return dec;
  } on Exception catch (e) {
    print(e.toString());
    rethrow;
  }
}

String encode(value) {
  try {
    final enc = json.encode(value);
    //print('enc = $enc');
    return enc;
  } on Exception catch (e) {
    print(e.toString());
    rethrow;
  }
}

void _test(String json, value) {
  test('$json <=> $value', () {
    final v1 = decode(json);
    final v2 = encode(value);
    final v3 = decode(v2);
    final v4 = encode(v3);
    final v5 = decode(v4);
    final v6 = encode(v5);
    expect(json, v2);
    expect(value, v1);
    expect(v1, v3);
    expect(v2, v4);
    expect(v3, v5);
    expect(v4, v6);
    expect(v5, value);
    expect(v6, json);
  });
}
```

Output:

```
00:00 +0: 1 <=> 1
00:00 +1: "a" <=> a
00:00 +2: {"a":1} <=> {a: 1}
00:00 +3: [1,"a"] <=> [1, a]
00:00 +4: All tests passed!
```

Comment: If you don't see any sense it does not mean it is absent.. ;) For example I have a class which saves `key/value of any type` pair into Web Session Storage.

Comment: I don't think your code means what you think it means. You are doing `json.decode(strJson)` where `strJson` is the string containing `a`. That's just not valid JSON. I don't know how that relates to your real problem, but as written it seems to assume that something is JSON source code when it's actually not. The code does not make sense in itself.

Comment: @lrn I've updated my answer and added example code for those people who don't understand that the author's algorithm is useless in that it doesn't convert values from one representation to another, but just does something useless.